# Function for CodeAcademy course returning absolute value for numbers produces error about maximum recursion depth

Tags: python

My code should use `abs()` to return the absolute value of an argument (called `distance_from_zero(n)`) when the argument is either '`int`' or '`float`'.  If the argument is anything else, like '`str`' then my code should return "Nope".

When I run my code on CodeAcademy, I get an error message

> "Oops, try again. It looks like you have an error in your code. Check
>   the error message for more info! - maximum recursion depth exceeded".

Can someone please tell me how the following code is wrong?

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    return distance_from_zero(n)

    if type(n) == int or type(n) == float:
        return abs(n)

    else:
        return "Nope"
```

edit: has been fixed, thank you!

Comment: What is the code `return distance_from_zero(n)` meant to do?

Comment: @Kevin I'm not actually sure, but codecadamy uses that in all their coding examples after defining the function and it marked it right in all my past codes

Comment: You're entering an infinite recursive loop on the second line. If you think about it you'll see why.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that all their functions start with a recursive call like this.

Answer (score 4):

You've defined a function that endlessly calls itself as its first action, which overflows your stack. That's what "Maximum recursion depth exceeded" means.

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    return distance_from_zero(n)  # calls itself which calls itself which ...
    # and it doesn't matter what else happens in this function, it'll never
    # actually get executed
```

`return` is the end point of the function. Once it reaches a `return` statement, the function ends. Putting `return <anything at all>` at the start of your function doesn't make sense.

Also, an aside: don't test with `type(foo) == some_type`, test with `isinstance(foo, some_type)`. This plays nicely with inheritance.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

type(d) == dict  # False
isinstance(d, dict)  # True
# you'll never want to treat a defaultdict as a non-dict entity
```

Comment: I'd say this function doesn't need type testing at all: just put it in a `try..except` and catch the `TypeError`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 absolutely agree, but I wanted to correct the bad habit I saw, not rewrite the function :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return distance_from_zero(n)` line. It keeps calling your function within itself causing an infinite loop.